# has_one through and accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-one-through

I'm trying to create a form to edit 2 object linked by a has_one through relationship :

bank_acount.rb

```
class BankAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :bank_account
  has_one :personal_information, through: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :personal_information
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  #...
end
```

personal_information.rb

```
class PersonalInformation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :personal_information
  #...
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :personal_information, inverse_of: :user
  has_one :bank_account, inverse_of: :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :personal_information
  #...
end
```

When I try to submit my form (here is a test to emulate that)

```
bank_account.update({:iban => 'XXX', :bic => 'XXX', personal_information_attributes: {
    first_name: 'first name',
    last_name: 'last name',
    address: 'address',
    zip: 'zip',
    city: 'city'
}})
```

I get this error :

```
ArgumentError: Cannot build association `personal_information'. Are you trying to build a polymorphic one-to-one association?
```

I do nothing with polymorphic stuff, and I don't know where this error come from.

Any idea?

Comment: If a user only `has_one :personal_information` and `has_one :bank_account` why are you separating `:personal_information` why not just add these columns to `User`? Also right now you can change `bank_account` to just `accept_nested_attributes_for :user` and then you can wrap `personal_information_attributes` inside `user_attributes` and it should work because `User` can `accept_nested_attributes_for :personal_information`.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion engineersmnky. but for some other reason it's not possible here